# Why a system app disappears unless updated?

Tags: applications, updates, root-access, system-apps

I happened on lollipop 5.1.1 and to one or two app at a time, for some reason the said app just won't show app in application list(and i can't use it)... ahh i can still see it in **system/app** or **system/priv-app**

When i attempt to reinstall the package manager behaves like am updating it and i can now use it(surprisingly my data and settings are all there as if i was just updating).

But again if integrate update into system using link2sd or manually move the app files from **data/app** to **system/app** or **system/priv-app** and fix permissions, the app disappears again...

Please help, i really find it pointless to have an anti-thief app on **data/** (everybody knows how to reset an android nowadays)..

I had an issue first with "google play services" on Sony C3 (didn't mind that then and decided i wont be integrating its updates to system) and now "avast anti-thief" on Samsung note 10.1, the devices have the same version of busybox installed and are both on stock android 5.1.1.

Comment: So the app disappears and doesn't run? Is the ownership set?

Comment: Rebooting after integrating should work.

Comment: Ni i have tried ut

Comment: Yes @Aoron Gillion the ownership matches other applications in there

Comment: Manually moving the app's files **isn't** a way to make an app into a system app.